# SEO - multi language site should subdomain or folder to separate each lang?

Tags: seo

I did see a post earlier about using subdomain but I'm not sure is it for country or what?

Ok, I've a site and I'm focusing only in US and Canada. But I will display english, chinese traditional and chinese simplified characters.

Should I use like

en.domain.com or www.domain.com/en for better SEO result?

Also what short code I should use for chinese traditional and chinese simplified characters?

Anyone knows? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `en.domain.com` if you don't have much content in English (or in the corresponding language - Chinese). Otherwise, both methods are fine from an SEO perspective.

Don't forget to use `hreflang`.